# jQuery get elements ID name from known dynamic class name

Tags: jquery

I have a value passed via a # in the url this is the class name of a checkbox what i am trying to do is get the value of that checkbox ID using jQuery

```
// get hashtag value
if(self.document.location.hash){
var urlhash = self.document.location.hash;
var hashtagval = self.document.location.hash.replace("#","");

// get id of element from hashtagval (class name)
var counter = $('.'+hashtagval).attr('id');
}
```

Comment: Ok, and what is your question? Beside that use `var hashtagval = urlhash.replace("#","");`

Comment: You probably need to wrap your function in a `$(document).ready(function() { /*...*/ } )`, since the element won't exist for targeting otherwise...but you should elaborate some more on what exactly the problem is.

Comment: my code does not work counter has no value it is undefined ?

Comment: I have wrapped it sorry I should of included that in my post
`
    // freegift //

 //  <input type="checkbox" name="giftSelect" value="<?=urlencode($t['freegift']);?>" id="freegiftid<?=$counter?>" />

 $(document).ready(function(){

  alert('use this value to call ajax and\n show relevant content\n' + hashtagval);

 //var class_name = '.'+hashtagval;

 var counter = $('.'+hashtagval).attr('id').replace('freegiftid','');

 freeGiftClick(counter);

 clickBtn();

 });`

Comment: @adrian You can edit your question to include the updated info, it's easier to read that way (there's an edit button right under the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I tested it and it works fine with adding #a and #b to the hash.

Beside you are abusing the hash attribute. The hash attribute is used to define a viewstate of the page (e.g. the screen should move to this paragraph) not to store some local varibles, which are then used for application logic!

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Demo</title>
            <script src="jquery.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var change = true;
                    $('#ba').click(function() {
                        // get hashtag value
                        if(self.document.location.hash) {
                            var urlhash = self.document.location.hash;
                            var hashtagval = self.document.location.hash.replace("#", "");

                            // get id of element from hashtagval (class name)
                            var id = $('.' + hashtagval).attr('id');
                            $('body').append('<h1>id=' + id);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <button type="button" id="ba" >
                Click Me!
            </button>

            <div>
                <p id="foundthisthing" class="a">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <p id="thisworkstoo"class="b">
                    eafdsaf dsa dgsf dgadg dfg dagfadgLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ha yes it does work it was because I had urlencoded class names